# JQuery cannot click on autocomplete drop down in firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

Here is my jquery code that was taken from their demo:

```
$(function() {
            var availableTags = [
                "val1",
                "val2",
                "val3",
                "val4",
                "val5"];
            function split( val ) {
                return val.split( /,\s*/ );
            }
            function extractLast( term ) {
                return split( term ).pop();
            }

            $('#tag')
                // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
                .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
                    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                        $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }).autocomplete({
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                        response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                            availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
                    },
                    focus: function() {
                        // prevent value inserted on focus
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                        var terms = split( this.value );
                        // remove the current input
                        terms.pop();
                        // add the selected item
                        terms.push( ui.item.value );
                        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                        terms.push( "" );
                        this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                        return false;
                    }
                });
        });
```

<`input type="text" name="tag" id="tag" autocomplete="on"/>`

This code was working until I added jquery validate on the drop down area. Is there anything I can do to be able to select with my mouse the option?

I am using knockout js if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that I was using the wrong jquery libraries.

Comment: what were the jquery libraries that you used ?

Comment: I think I had a jquery ui version that wasn't compatible with my jquery version. It was awhile ago so I am unsure but it is working with the latest jquery libraries as far as I know.